# Missing ssl_crtd folder with Squid 3.5.2 / CentOS

Tags: centos, squid

I am attempting to install Squid 3.5.2 to utilize improved sslbump functionality with websites with HSTS. I'm following the [documentation](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/KnowledgeBase/CentOS) on a fresh CentOS 7 VM installation. The issue I'm having is that there is no ssl_crtd folder created when Squid is installed, despite the fact the rpm appears to have been configured with the appropriate switches.

See below for output of Squid -v

```
[root@squid]# squid -v
Squid Cache: Version 3.5.2
Service Name: squid
configure options:  '--build=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' '--host=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' '--program-prefix=' '--prefix=/usr' '--exec-prefix=/usr' '--bindir=/usr/bin' '--sbindir=/usr/sbin' '--sysconfdir=/etc' '--datadir=/usr/share' '--includedir=/usr/include' '--libdir=/usr/lib64' '--libexecdir=/usr/libexec' '--sharedstatedir=/var/lib' '--mandir=/usr/share/man' '--infodir=/usr/share/info' '--exec_prefix=/usr' '--libexecdir=/usr/lib64/squid' '--localstatedir=/var' '--datadir=/usr/share/squid' '--sysconfdir=/etc/squid' '--with-logdir=$(localstatedir)/log/squid' '--with-pidfile=$(localstatedir)/run/squid.pid' '--disable-dependency-tracking' '--enable-follow-x-forwarded-for' '--enable-auth' '--enable-auth-basic=DB,LDAP,NCSA,NIS,PAM,POP3,RADIUS,SASL,SMB,getpwnam' '--enable-auth-ntlm=smb_lm,fake' '--enable-auth-digest=file,LDAP,eDirectory' '--enable-auth-negotiate=kerberos,wrapper' '--enable-external-acl-helpers=wbinfo_group,kerberos_ldap_group,AD_group' '--enable-cache-digests' '--enable-cachemgr-hostname=localhost' '--enable-delay-pools' '--enable-epoll' '--enable-icap-client' '--enable-ident-lookups' '--enable-linux-netfilter' '--enable-removal-policies=heap,lru' '--enable-snmp' '--enable-storeio=aufs,diskd,ufs,rock' '--enable-wccpv2' '--enable-esi' '--enable-ssl-crtd' '--enable-icmp' '--with-aio' '--with-default-user=squid' '--with-filedescriptors=16384' '--with-dl' '--with-openssl' '--with-pthreads' '--with-included-ltdl' '--disable-arch-native' '--without-nettle' 'build_alias=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' 'host_alias=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' 'CFLAGS=-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches   -m64 -mtune=generic' 'LDFLAGS=-Wl,-z,relro ' 'CXXFLAGS=-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches   -m64 -mtune=generic -fPIC' 'PKG_CONFIG_PATH=%{_PKG_CONFIG_PATH}:/usr/lib64/pkgconfig:/usr/share/pkgconfig' --enable-ltdl-convenience
```

Does anyone know why that folder, which as I've read in almost all documentation *should* be there is strangely absent?

EDIT :

The directory I'm looking for is the ssl_crtd directory. From the documentation I've read it appears as though it should be located in `/usr/lib64/squid/ssl_crtd`. Trying to locate it with the `find / -name "ssl_*"` (and other variations) command turns up nothing either.

Comment: Exactly what directory are you looking for?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Edited for clarity - sorry about the omission.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ssl_crtd is a binary it is built in the squid-helpers rpm build
see: squid.spec.

```
%files helpers
%{_libdir}/squid/basic_db_auth
%{_libdir}/squid/basic_getpwnam_auth
%{_libdir}/squid/basic_ldap_auth
%{_libdir}/squid/basic_ncsa_auth
%{_libdir}/squid/basic_nis_auth
%{_libdir}/squid/basic_pam_auth
%{_libdir}/squid/basic_pop3_auth
.........
%{_libdir}/squid/ssl_crtd
```

If you want it installed in the general squid rpm you must modify the squid.spec file to copy the lib installer into the %files section of the spec file or install squid-helpers.rpm

Comment: Installing the squid-helpers.rpm resolved the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You must created the certificate storage yourself. Type the following commands to do it (these are for Ubuntu but CentOS should be quite similar):

```
$ sudo rm -R -f /var/spool/squid3_ssldb
$ sudo /bin/ssl_crtd -c -s /var/spool/squid3_ssldb
$ sudo chown -R proxy:proxy /var/spool/squid3_ssldb
```

Finally restart your Squid proxy.

```
$ sudo service squid3 restart
```

More info at http://docs.diladele.com/administrator_guide_4_1/system_configuration/https_filtering/generate_certificates.html

Comment: Hi Rafael - Unfortunately step 2 doesn't work in this example as the /bin/ssl_crtd directory does not exist. Does that need to be manually created as well?

Answer (score 0):

Visit http://roberts.bplaced.net/index.php/linux-guides/centos-6-guides/proxy-server/squid-transparent-proxy-http-https

> STEP 2 - Enable EPEL repo, install SQUID
>
> CentOS provided SQUID does not have ssl_crtd for some reason, ...

Comment: and

"yum install squid-helpers"

Answer (score -1):

The `ssl_crtd` is in the `squid-helpers` package.
In an x86_64 installation, it is found in path `/usr/lib64/squid/ssl_crtd`